# Protection of sensor and electrical wire conduits/trays from water

Tags: wiring, cables

I have an application where I have to use a couple of temperature sensors and some electrical wires running around a container (l x b x h = 2.3 x 12 x 2.6 m) that is situated outdoors. The electrical wires basically are coming from and going to a PLC and cable conduits or cable trays will be used for cable passage. which is the best one (cost-effective) to use, cable conduits or cable trays when concerned with protection from water? How can I safeguard my sensors and the electrical cable conduits /trays from rainwater/snow? What can be the protection possibilities?

Comment: If the cable is continuous, then the insulation is the thing you're trying to protect from water. So just select suitable wires with correctly rated insulation.

Answer (score 1):

I have hundreds of sensors out in the rain, you just need to select ones rated for out door use. I preferr 24 volt models if your rack is 24 volt there is less chance of problems with water. The only one I could see a problem with is the thermocouple. If only high temp fiber insulation when the cable gets wet it can mess up your voltage and give inaccurate readings. This is solved with plastic insulationon the wires or the outer sheith. I like low voltage because I can have the wire going in free air to the mount where if 120v the eye or prox would need to be mounted in the junction box to protect the wires.